# How to use array_key_exists in foreach loop for JSON

Tags: php

I have some code that iterates over JSON in my project to display reviews in a slider. This code works, however I only want to display reviews where the array key 'comment' exists. I feel like the solution must be using [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), but I can't get the code correct (I'm still quite a novice with PHP). I've tried searching all over SO without much success. Here's an example of some of the JSON I'm working with; REVIEW ID 1 is review that I want to display, and REVIEW ID 2 is one I want to skip:

```
{
  "reviewId": "{REVIEW ID 1}",
  "reviewer": {
    "profilePhotoUrl": "{PROFILE PHOTO URL}",
    "displayName": "PERSON 1"
  },
  "starRating": "FIVE",
  "comment": "This is a review",
  "createTime": "2019-08-30T15:38:59.412Z",
  "updateTime": "2019-08-30T15:38:59.412Z",
  "reviewReply": {
    "comment": "{REVIEW REPLY}",
    "updateTime": "2019-08-30T16:05:58.184Z"
  },
  "name": "accounts/{ACCOUNT NUMBER}/locations/{LOCATION NUMBER}/reviews/"
},
{
  "reviewId": "{REVIEW ID 2}",
  "reviewer": {
    "profilePhotoUrl": "{PROFILE PHOTO URL}",
    "displayName": "PERSON 2"
  },
  "starRating": "FIVE",
  "createTime": "2019-02-07T14:59:28.729Z",
  "updateTime": "2019-02-07T14:59:28.729Z",
  "name": "accounts/{ACCOUNT NUMBER}/locations/{LOCATION NUMBER}/reviews/"
},
```

And here's the code that runs the reviews:

```
    $jsonreviews = plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . './latest.json';
    $reviews2var = file_get_contents($jsonreviews);
    $reviews = json_decode($reviews2var, true);
    $starpath = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . './img/fivestars.svg';
    $truckpath = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . './img/chad_love_truck.png';

    // Start buffer
    ob_start();
?>
    <div class="reviews-background">
     <div class="swiper-container review-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper review-wrapper">
         <?php
            $counter = 1;
             foreach ($reviews['reviews'] as $review) :
                if ($counter > 3)  {
                    //do nothing
                } else {
         ?>
            <div class="swiper-slide review-slide">
             <img src="<?php echo $starpath;?>" alt="5 Stars" class="five-stars" />

                <?php   $counter++;?>
                 <div class="truncate" data-excerpt>
                  <div data-excerpt-content>
                    <p class="slider-review-text">
                     <?php echo $review['comment'];?></p>
                  </div>
                 </div>

                  <p class="slider-review-auth">
                   <?php echo $review['reviewer']['displayName'];?>,
                  </p>
              </div>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
```

How can I properly implement array_key_exists in the above, or should I be doing something else entirely? Thank you

Comment: Maybe something like JSONpath https://github.com/FlowCommunications/JSONPath https://github.com/Galbar/JsonPath-PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `comment` is NOT set here:

```
if ($counter > 3 || !isset($review['comment']))  {
    //do nothing
} else {
    $counter++;
    //HTML
}
```

However, I would probably flip the `if` logic and you won't need an `else`:

```
if ($counter <= 3 && isset($review['comment']))  {
    $counter++;
    //HTML
}
```

If you have large arrays, you probably want to break out of the loop if you have displayed more than 3 (or some number):

```
if ($counter > 3)
    break;
} elseif (isset($review['comment']))  {
    $counter++;
    //HTML
}
```

You can substitute `!array_key_exists` and `array_key_exists` for the `isset`s if you want.

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simple approach

```
if(isset($test[$key_check])){
    echo  $value = $test[$key_check];
}
```

Or check for array exist :

```
if (array_key_exists($key_check, $test)) {
    return $test[$key_check];
}
```